# MySQL for Concrete5 database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm adding a custom block to Concrete5. The db.xml file for the block is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <schema version="0.3">
    <table name="btConferences">
      <field name="bID" type="I">
        <key />
        <unsigned />
      </field>
      <field name="title" type="C"></field>
      <field name="openDate" type="TS"></field>
      <field name="closeDate" type="TS"></field>
      <field name="overview" type="X2"></field>
    </table>
  </schema>
```

Unfortunately, as simple as I think this db.xml is, Concrete5 will not load it without error. I get the following message when i try to install the block:

`mysqlt error: [1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' openDate DATETIME, closeDate DATETIME, overview ' at line 3] in EXECUTE("CREATE TABLE btConferences ( bID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, title VARCHAR, openDate DATETIME, closeDate DATETIME, overview LONGTEXT, PRIMARY KEY (bID) )")`

Unfortunately, I'm not good enough with SQL to spot the error here. If someone could point out the error, I might be able to fix the db.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VARCHAR` requires you to specify a character size, so MySQL can figure out how much space to allocate to that field. You don't have a size specification, so it's an error:

```
foo VARCHAR,     // wrong, no size
foo VARCHAR(10), // correct, 10 chars max.
```

e.g:

```
mysql> create table foo (x varchar);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
mysql> create table foo (x varchar(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```